# Image rounding on Android but not on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

Edit 3: What worked for me

```
          <View 
            style={{
              minHeight: 200
            }}
          >
            <Image
              resizeMode="contain"
              source={{ uri: props.item.thumbnailURL }}
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                width: 350,
                height: 200,
                borderBottomLeftRadius: 30,
                borderBottomRightRadius: 30,
                borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
                borderTopRightRadius: 30,
                borderColor: "orange",
                borderWidth: 1,
                overflow: "hidden",
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignSelf: "center",
              }}
            />
          </View>
```

Edit 2: Added full code

Edit: I added
`borderWidth: 3, borderColor: "orange"`

and noticed that the parent of the image is rounding [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFMQj.jpg) ... But why? I didn't want that.

I also tried with
`borderRadius: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 30/2 : 30` but it didn't have any effect. What more can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify border radius value for all of the corners for ios
for example:

```
{
  flex: 1,
  width: 350,
  height: 200,
  borderRadius:30,
  overflow: "hidden",
  borderBottomLeftRadius: 30,
  borderBottomRightRadius: 30,
  borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
  borderTopRightRadius: 30,
}
```

Comment: It's rounding the parent's corners, not the image. I am testing on Iphone 6s,  iOS 14.4.1

Comment: Can you share full code?

Comment: Added the full code in the post

Comment: I think if you set width and height for the View as container and set flex: 1 for image solves the problem!